# Functional derivative for compostion of functional

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, functional-calculus

Is it possible to obtain the functional derivative of the following functional?

$Z[q]=\int_0^T\int_0^t\int_0^t q(t'')K(t''-t')q(t')dt''dt'dt.$

I tried to apply the usual functional derivative definition [(like here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative):

$\delta Z=\frac{\delta Z}{\delta q}= \frac{d}{d\epsilon}[\int_0^T\int_0^t\int_0^t (q(t'')+\epsilon \phi(t''))K(t''-t')(q(t')+\epsilon\phi(t'))dt''dt'dt]_{\epsilon=0}$

$\frac{\delta Z}{\delta q}= \int_0^T\int_0^t\int_0^t \phi(t'')K(t''-t')q(t') + q(t'')K(t''-t')\phi(t')  dt''dt'dt$

But I can't see the end.
Someone can help me?

Thanks!